# Yii2: Почему в методе beforeDelete hasMany возвращает null?

Tags: yii2

Я пытаюсь удалить связанные документы перед удалением комплекса

Модель комплекса:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getComplexDocument()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ComplexDocument::className(), ['complex_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getDocuments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Documents::className(), ['id' => 'document_id'])
        ->via('complexDocument');
}

public function beforeDelete()
{        
    foreach ($this->documents as $document){
        var_dump($document);
    }
    return parent::beforeDelete();
}
```

Удаление не происходит, проверил, все hasMany атрибуты возвращают NULL.

Дебаг [image: дебаг]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сделал таким образом:

```
public function delete()
{ 
    ...
    foreach ($this->documents as $document){
        $document->delete();
    }
    $this->image->delete();
    ...
}
```

Все работает, все связанные документы удаляются, но мне это кажется странным. По сути это должно быть в beforeDelete(), но почему там связи не возвращаются и соответственно не удаляются, так и должно быть или это недоработка фреймворка?